# How to use unicode character for truncation and wrap slots in the standard display table

Tags: unicode, buffer-display-table

I'm trying to set unicode characters for the truncation and wrap slots in the standard display table (see code below) that are used in terminal mode or GUI when there is no fringe. It is working for truncated lines, but not for wrapped lines: the `↩︎` is not displayed and is replaced by an hollow box. I suspect I may have to use `make-glyph-code` but I'm not sure of the syntax.

```
(set-display-table-slot standard-display-table 'truncation ?…)
(set-display-table-slot standard-display-table 'wrap       ?↩︎)
```

**Solution**:

The problem was the "↩︎" glyph being substituted by the glyph from a fallback font (Fira Code in my case). I'm not sure this is a bug but here is the solution:

```
(defface fallback '((t :family "Fira Code"))  "Display")
(set-display-table-slot standard-display-table 'wrap
                        (make-glyph-code ?↩ 'fallback))
```

Comment: This is interesting ... The only `word-wrap` looking character I have seen is a bitmap image that appears on the fringe for GUI versions of Emacs, or built-in to the display for terminal versions and GUI versions with no fringe.  How can we as forum participants generate a minimal working example of what you term as `'wrap` or `wrap slots`?

Comment: Just to clarify, what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Is there an error, or does it use the wrong character? I ask because your wrap character is a LEFTWARDS ARROW WITH HOOK followed by a VARIATIONAL SELECTOR-15, which give a syntax error; I guess the lisp parser doesn't like combining characters in that read syntax.

Comment: For GUI, you need to remove the fringe and emacs will use the character in the display-table-slot for indicating a truncated (default is `$`) or wrapped line (default is `\`). The term slot comes from the documentation of the `set-display-table-slot` function.

Comment: @db48x Thansk, the VARIATIONAL SELECTOR-15 was an error. I clarified the question.

Comment: ↩︎ cannot work, gui emacs only displays a bordered block, but ¬ works.Perhaps because ¬ belongs to : [Latin-1 Supplement](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Latin-1_Supplement_(Unicode_block)) but ↩︎ is a complicated unicode? [Arrows (Unicode block) - Wikiwand](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Arrows_(Unicode_block))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(set-display-table-slot·buffer-display-table 'wrap ?↩)` works for me, with one caveat. In a terminal the arrow shows up correctly, but in the gui (with fringe-mode turned off), the glyph is drawn with a replacement character; apparently it couldn't find a glyph for the arrow in the chosen font. It does render correctly in the scratch buffer, but it's using a slightly different font in the fringe.

Note that in the code you put in your question, you have a second character after the `?`, which makes it invalid syntax. I assume the error you're getting is `(invalid-read-syntax "?")`, since you didn't say.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. `describe-char` tells me the font for the glyph is actually different. But I don't understand why the substitution is not made during the display.

Comment: It apparently just doesn't use font fallback when drawing those characters. It might just be an oversight; you could use `M-x report-emacs-bug` and find out.

Comment: Can you test with emacs-27 or emacs-master first, before opening a bug?